# Apply Mask in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I start out with this image:[image]

for which I want to color in the lane markings directly in front of the vehicle (yes this is for a Udacity online class, but they want me to do this in python, but I'd rather do it in C++)

Finding the right markers is easy:
[image]

This works for coloring the markers:

```
  cv::MatIterator_<cv::Vec3b> output_pix_it = output.begin<cv::Vec3b>(); 
  cv::MatIterator_<cv::Vec3b> output_end = output.end<cv::Vec3b>();

  cv::MatIterator_<cv::Vec3b> mask_pix_it = lane_markers.begin<cv::Vec3b>(); 

  //auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

  while (output_pix_it != output_end)
  {
    if((*mask_pix_it)[0] == 255)
    {
      (*output_pix_it)[0] = 0;
      (*output_pix_it)[1] = 0;
      (*output_pix_it)[2] = 255;
    }

    ++output_pix_it;
    ++mask_pix_it;
  }
```

correctly producing
[image]

however I was a little surprised that it seemed to be kind of slow, taking 1-2 ms (on a core i7-7700HQ w/ 16gb ram, compiled with `-O3`) for the image which is 960 x 540

Following "the efficient way" here: https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/core/how_to_scan_images/how_to_scan_images.html#howtoscanimagesopencv

I came up with:

```
    unsigned char *o; // pointer to first element in output Mat
    unsigned char *m; //pointer to first element in mask Mat
    o = output.data;
    m = lane_markers.data;
    size_t pixel_elements = output.rows * output.cols * output.channels();

    for( size_t i=0; i < pixel_elements; i+=3 )
    {
      if(m[i] == 255)
      {
        o[i] = 0;
        o[i+1] = 0;
        o[i+2] = 255;
      }
    }
```

which is about 3x faster....but doesn't produce the correct results:
[image]

All cv::Mat objects are of type 8UC3 type (standard BGR pixel format).
As far as I can tell the underlying data of the Mat objects should be an array of `unsigned char`s of the length pixel width * pixel height * num channels. But it seems like I'm missing something.  `isContinuous()` is true for both the output and mask matrices. I'm using openCV 3.4.4 on Ubuntu 18.04. What am I missing?

Comment: Why do you consider _1-2 ms_ slow?

Comment: And what exactly are you asking? _"What am I missing"_ is too broad

Comment: @nada from experience, for the operation being performed it just seemed it should've been faster than it was. Using the `setTo()`  function as mentioned in the answer applies the mask in about 45 us or about 25x to 40x faster.  In this case it looks like they might be using CUDA and the GPU under the hood to get that kind of speed up. In vision pipelines such as this minimizing latency is critical to having a responsive control system. It still drives me a little nuts that my hack wasn't working, but I guess oh well. The given answer is a much better solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typical way of setting a masked area of a `Mat` to a specific value is to use [`Mat::setTo`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-setto) function:

```
cv::Mat mask;
cv::cvtColor(lane_markers, mask, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY); //mask Mat has to be 8UC1
output.setTo(cv::Scalar(0, 0, 255), mask);
```

Comment: I knew there had to be a function that did that, I just couldn't figure out what it was.  That is fantastic.  And it's significantly (25x - 40x) faster--about 45us.